# Struggling Immensly multi tenancy Sharepoint on Existing Sharepoint Server

Tags: multi-tenancy, https

Really strugging with this for last month, going to have another crack this weekend but ideally simply need to create multi tenancy sharepoint 2010 all in https using domains similar to below;

https://mysharepointcompany.com/companyA

or even;

https://mysharepointcompany.com/sites/companyA

Just can't crack it, i've read Harbar's but when i try fail, i'll admit not sharepoint guru but would love to nai

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your post is a bit vague and you need to provide details of what exactly isn't working.

Harbar is the best resource out there for setting up multi-tenancy and works fine for me. Are you following all the steps exactly?

Also, did you use AutoSPInstaller to install and configure your farm? AutoSPInstaller is great for single-tenancy deployments, but configures the service applications incorrectly for multi-tenancy deployments.

Comment: I know, thanks Colin, i did use autospinstaller which is brilliant!

This weekend will have another stab, i stuggle to understand exactly how it works i guess more or logical how it fits and i think i get issues when running the last provision section and site subscriptions!

Thanks, will let you know how i get on, appreciated.